# CAML Returning Tomorrow's Value when filtering Today

Tags: caml-query

I have the following CAML query for SP2003

```
SPQuery qry = new SPQuery();
qry.ExpandRecurrence = true;
qry.CalendarDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

qry.Query = "<Where><And><DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\" /><FieldRef Name=\"EndDate\" />" +
"<FieldRef Name=\"RecurrenceID\" /><Value Type=\"DateTime\"><Today /></Value></DateRangesOverlap>" +
"<Eq><FieldRef Name=\"User\" LookupId=\"true\" /><Value Type=\"Integer\">" + uvEmployee.LookupId.ToString() + "</Value></Eq></And></Where>";
```

Which returns me an all day event which is occuring tomorrow. Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on this? I use <Where><DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name="EventDate" /><FieldRef Name="EndDate" /><FieldRef Name="RecurrenceID" /><Value Type="DateTime">2012-01-30T00:00:00Z</Value></DateRangesOverlap></Where> Instead of <Today/> using the SPUtility you mentioned. However when I run SQL profile the query date is far apart. The date becomes @L4DTP='2013-01-29 16:00:00',@L5DTP='2011-01-29 16:00:01' Not exactly sure why. Is it I need to do something at eventsQuery.CalendarDate = queryDate; Which the queryDate is something like 12/26/2011 12:00:00 AM format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is just me, but I have not had much luck getting the Today to work in my environment. I use "sputility.createiso8601datetimefromsystemdatetime" on todays date and this always works.

Comment: Yeah same here, I've always had to replace it with the same.

Answer (score 0):

The string value from the column is in iso8601 format, and is in correct Zulu time.

`<Today/>` string value from CAML is in the same format, but is the current date time of the server time zone.

Compare the 2 values directly and you'll be out by however many hours your current time zone is.

Using

> SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(DateTime.Now)

as mentioned above, will give the compatible "today" string value to compare to the column value.