# CAMLQuery Comparison

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query

I'm trying to perform a **CAML Query** test and display the results.

For example I'll be using two columns in a list; one called **StartDate** another called **EndDate**.

Currently, I've a CAML Query that orders the StartDate column and displays the first five items in the list.

```
    CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='StartDate' Ascending='True'/></OrderBy></Query>",
    CAMLRowLimit: 5,
```

What I need to do is to write something that will look at the EndDate column and make a comparison to today's date.  If that date has already passed it shouldn't turn up in the results.

Therefore, the 5 list items appearing will not have an EndDate that has already passed.

Comment: Take a look at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/caml-now-instead-of-today-caml-bug The <WHERE> snippet at the very top of the page might be really close to what you need - I believe you'll need to place it here in your Query <Query><OrderBy /><Where /></Query>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to add `where` condition and use `<Today>` token in your caml query. The query will be like as below

```
<OrderBy>
    <FieldRef Name='StartDate' Ascending='True'/>
</OrderBy>
<Where>
    <Geq>
        <FieldRef Name='EndDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value>
    </Geq>
</Where>
```

Reference: http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2009/06/using-today-token-in-caml-query.html

Comment: Perfect! I just modified the Today value to include the future 10 days as well.  <Today OffsetDays="5" />  Works like a charm.  Much appreciated!